# Динамический id тега в Angular директиве

Tags: angularjs

На странице создается несколько контейнеров с помощью директивы, и каждому контейнеру подставляется id, a **new Map** ищет контейнер c **id** и создает в нем мировую карту с помощью **canvas** и **KineticJS**. Карт на странице может быть несколько. И проблема в том, что если заменить в директиве подстановку id={{ wId }} на жестко заданное значание все отрабатывает, а вот с подставым id'шником неработает.

> Error: a is null
>   ._buildDOM@http:*\\localhost:4000/vendor/graphics/kinetic/v4.7.0/kinetic-v4.7.0.min.js:3:27637*
>   .___init@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/graphics/kinetic/v4.7.0/kinetic-v4.7.0.min.js:3:21801*
>   Kinetic.Stage@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/graphics/kinetic/v4.7.0/kinetic-v4.7.0.min.js:2:652*
>   Map/this.draw@*http:\\localhost:4000/scripts/map.canvas.js:821:22*
>   map_link_handler@*http:\\localhost:4000/app/modules/widgets/metrics.widgets.js:236:13*
>   cloneAndAnnotateFn/<@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:8835:41*
>   invokeLinkFn@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:8841:9*
>   nodeLinkFn@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:8335:1*
>   compositeLinkFn@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:7731:13*
>   compositeLinkFn@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:7734:13*
>   publicLinkFn@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:7611:30*
>   createBoundTranscludeFn/boundTranscludeFn@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:7749:1*
>   controllersBoundTransclude@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:8362:18*
>   ngSwitchWatchAction/<@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:28147:13*
>   forEach@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:340:11*
>   ngSwitchWatchAction@http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:28146:11
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:15896:23
>   $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:16160:13
>   done@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:10589:36*
>   completeRequest@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:10787:7*
>   requestLoaded@*http:\\localhost:4000/vendor/angular/angular-1.4.8.js:10728:1*

```js
function m_widget() {
  return {
    name: 'mWidget',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    templateUrl: '/app/modules/widgets/directives/templates/m-widget.html',
    scope: {
      wId: '@',
      wType: '@',
      wData: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.wTitle = titleFromType(scope.wType);

      // Get widget title from widget type
      function titleFromType(type) {
        // ...
      }
    }
  }
}

map_widget.$inject = ['$compile'];

function map_widget($compile) {
  return {
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div id="{{ wId }}"></div>',
    scope: {
      wId: '@on'
    },
    link: map_link_handler
  };

  function map_link_handler(scope, element, attrs) {
    var parent = element.parent().get(0);
    element.css({
      width: parent.clientWidth,
      height: parent.clientWidth * 0.7
    });

    var map = new Map(attrs['id'], '', {
      zoom: 'WORLD'
    });
    map.draw();
  }
}
```

```html
<m-widget ng-repeat="widget in widgets" w-id="{{ widget.id }}" w-type="{{ widget.type }}" w-data="widget.data"></m-widget>

<!-- m-widget -->
<div class="panel panel-default box" m-draggable>
  <div class="panel-heading">{{ wTitle }}</div>
  <ng-switch on="wType">
    <div class="panel-body" ng-switch-when="map">
      <m-widget-map on="{{ wId }}"></m-widget-map>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" ng-switch-when="pie">PIE</div>
    <div class="panel-body" ng-switch-when="hbar">HBar</div>
    <div class="panel-body" ng-switch-when="vbar">VBar</div>
    <div class="panel-body" ng-switch-when="list">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in wData">{{ item.country }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" ng-switch-when="dial">Dial</div>
    <div class="panel-body" ng-switch-when="table">Table</div>
    <div class="panel-body" ng-switch-when="label">Lable</div>
    <div class="panel-body" ng-switch-when="number">Number</div>
  </ng-switch>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вы сами нашли ответ на свой вопрос, стоит оформить его в виде ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение в общем оказалось простым. Вместо подстановки **id="{{ wId }}"** в **template** директивы. Нужно подстановку вынести в **link** директивы - **element.attr('id', 'canvasID)**.